# Why is $\mathbb{P}(X<Y) = \mathbb{P}(Y<X)$ for two independent random variables with same mass function?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables taking values in the positive integers and having the same mass function. Why is it that

$$ \mathbb{P}(X<Y) = \mathbb{P}(Y<X). $$

---

I understand that

$$ \begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y>X) &= 1- \mathbb{P}(Y\le X)\\
 &= 1- \mathbb{P}(X=Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y<X). 
\end{align*}$$

For the mass function $f(x)=2^{-x}$, $x=1,2,\dots$ I found that

$$ \mathbb{P}(X=Y) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x)f(x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty4^{-x}=\frac{1}{3}. $$

This yields that

$$ \mathbb{P}(X<Y)+\mathbb{P}(Y<X)=\frac{2}{3}. $$

So if $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\mathbb{P}(Y<X)$ I see that this is $\frac{1}{3}$, but I don't understand why they are the same.

Comment: The variables are independent and identically distributed, in other words, how can you tell which one is X and which one is Y? I mean, if I tell you I've randomly drawn two balls from two different urns with the same distribution of coloured balls inside. How can you tell which ball was drawn from which urn?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Ah yeah, I think I get it. Thanks! That kind of examples are really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not even sure they have to be independent (after all correlation is symmetric), but in the independence case:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(Y\lt X) &= \mathbb{P}(Y-X \lt 0)\\
&=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(Y-X \lt 0\;|\;X=t)\cdot\phi_X\cdot\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(Y\lt t )\cdot\phi_X\cdot\mathrm{d}t\end{align}\\$$

And similarly: $\mathbb{P}(X\lt Y) =
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X\lt t )\cdot\phi_Y\cdot\mathrm{d}t\\$, but since $\phi_X=\phi_Y$ (the respective densities) and $\mathbb{P}(X\lt t )=\mathbb{P}(Y\lt t )$ the two probabilities are equivalent; (someone please correct any flaws in this!) Cheers

Comment: Your argument very much uses independence, when you declare that $P(Y-X<0\mid X=t)=P(Y<t)$.

Comment: you're completely right, sorry not awake yet, will edit!

Comment: edited to remove the claim that the argument proves redundancy of independence, hope that is better? still convinced for 2 RVs independence is not required, just haven't written out a proof of this (unless am mistaken here too) Anyway thanks very much for pointing out error.