# Discrete Independent random variables X and Y

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, taking values in the positive integers and having the same mass function $f(x)=2^{-x}$ for $x=1,2,..... \infty$
>   Find  $P(Y\gt X)$.

---

Here's what I did,
$P(Y \gt X) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \{P(Y \ge x,X \le x) - P(Y=x,X=x)\}$
I think this equation is correct because; for any arbitary $x$, we must have $X$ smaller than it, and $Y$ greater than it (that is the first part). Then I subtract the probability that both of them are equal to $x$ (the second part).

$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}P(Y=x,X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(Y=x)P(X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} 4^{-x} = \frac 13$

$P(Y \ge x,X \le x)=P(Y \ge x)P(X \le x) = P(X \le x) .(1-P(Y\le x) + P(Y=x)) $

After this, I solved for $P(X \le x)$ and $P(Y \le x)$ using the mass distribution function.

Next I just solved simplified the equations until I got the answer.
I know there is something wrong as I get the probability as $1$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint on another solution: P(X<Y)=P(Y<X), because they are i.i.d.

Comment: @mzg147 If someone's looking for that solution->  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031304/why-is-mathbbpxy-mathbbpyx-for-two-independent-random-variables

Comment: Your first equation is not correct; there is a lot of double-counting going on. (Imagine that $X$ and $Y$ each took the values $2$ and $17$ with probability $\frac12$ each, for example; would that equation be correct?)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you could use that $P(Y<X) = P(X<Y)$ since they are IID. But your initial step is wrong as there is a whole lot of double counting happening. Instead of that try writing(more along your approach) $$P(Y>X) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}P(X = x, Y>x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}P(X=x)(1 - P(Y \leq x))$$ Since the variables are independent.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

$$P(Y>X)=$$
$$=P(Y=2)P(X=1)+P(Y=3)P(X=1)+\cdots$$

$$+P(Y=3)P(X=2)+P(Y=4)P(X=2)+\cdots$$

$$+P(Y=4)P(X=3)+P(Y=5)P(X=3)+\cdots$$
$$\cdots=$$

$$=2^{-3}+2^{-4}+\cdots$$
$$+2^{-5}+2^{-6}+\cdots$$
$$+2^{-7}+2^{-8}+\cdots$$
$$\cdots=$$

$$=2^{-2}+$$
$$=2^{-4}+$$
$$=2^{-6}+$$
$$\cdots$$
$$=\frac13.$$

As $$P(X=Y)=P(X<Y)=P(Y<X).$$

Comment: No. $\mathsf P(Y=X)$ will be non-zero, so $\mathsf P(X>Y)$ and $\mathsf P(Y>X)$ cannot both be $1/2$.

Comment: Rather, $\sum_{1\leq x<y}2^{-x-y}~{=\sum_{x=1}^\infty2^{-x}\sum_{y=x+1}^\infty2^{-y}\\=2^{-3}+2^{-4}\,{+2^{-5}+2^{-6}+2^{-7}+\cdots\\+2^{-5}+2^{-6}\,{+2^{-7}+\cdots\\{+2^{-7}+{\cdots\\\ddots}}}}\\=2^{-2}\quad+2^{-4}\quad+2^{-6}+\cdots\\=\sum_{x=1}^\infty 4^{-x}\\=\ldots}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Uh! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mathsf P(Y<X)+\mathsf P(Y=X)+\mathsf P(Y>X)=1$ and $\mathsf P(Y>X)=\mathsf P(Y<X)$ so...$$\mathsf P(Y>X)=\tfrac 12-\tfrac 12\sum_{x=1}^\infty 2^{-2x}$$